# How to make changes to wordpress without them going live immediately?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to make very quick and easy css changes to a website that is wordpress site. I dont want make them while the site is live. is there a way to make them locally and then upload? what do you recommend?

people tell me that doing it locally is a big hassle because of the way the server is. is there a plug in that will let me make changes without them going live?

Thank you very much in advanced...sorry this is my first time with wordpress

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is the following:

a) Install wamp server on your pc. (google where to get it)

b) Install a version of wordpress locally - in case you already have a version online that want to work on you will have to transfer it locallly. check this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Actually you are saving your wordpress database, download all the files inside your wamp\www folder and then import the database through phpmyadmin to your local wamp server and change a couple of options in the db > options table (there are two options to change the website that is loaded so that it looks locally)

c) Your work on the offline version. I assume you mean that you need only styling, so you can edit your style.css file. As soon as you are pleased with it, you just upload it on your web server replacing your old file!

Comment: Hi I installed MAMP (im on a mac) and I also installed wordpress. Are you saying all i have to do now is move all the wordpress files to my mamp/htcdoc folder? I have them already in there but it does not load when I run my mamp server and click on the directory for the site maybe the codex will help ill try it out thank you

Comment: You also have to download the database from your webserver and replace your local one. This is usually done using phpmyadmin and exporting the database in a file, but it actually depends on the control panel your webhost is using. So, to sum up, you need to do two things, 1) download the files and 2) download the database. Then replace the files with the ones found locally. As for the database, after you replace it, you need to change 2 values in the options table of the db. edit: also you have to change the wp-config.php file so that it matched the connection of your local database.

Comment: I will try to find some extra info online and get back to you. edit: check this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL Also check the link I previously posted to study the procedure of migrating a wordpress version: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

same as @scooterlord .

You can use nginx and php-cgi too on your Windows if ya wanna move to nginx in future.

Just install wamp then then download Wordpress version and then download your theme or plugin on which ya wanna work.

So ya will able to work offline and its not effect ur website.

yeah.  I ya download db from ur site  u need to change url of wordpress in DB.

u can do it by using phpmyadmin.

or by using These lines in your themes function file.:

```
 update_option('siteurl','http://your.site.url:port/yourblog');
 update_option('home','http://your.site.url:port/yourblog');
```